# algorithms to detect and break down arithmetic or geometric sequence

Tags: algorithm, sequence, analysis

If a sequence is pure arithmetic `(1,3,5,7,9...)` or pure geometric `(3,9,27,81...)`, its easy to detect.

How about a "mixed" arithmetic/geometric sequence ?

```
e.g. 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 14
it contain 3 arithmetic sequences (3 6 9), (3 5 7 9) and (2 6 10 14) in it.

e.g. 2 3 4 8 9 16 27 32 81
it contain 2 geometric sequences (2 4 8 16 32) and (3 9 27 81) in it.

e.g. 2 3 4 5 8 9 16 32
it contain 1 geometric sequence (2 4 8 16 32) and 2 arithmetic sequences (2 3 4 5) (3 5 7 9) in it.
```

(assume sequence should contain more than 2 elements)

Is there any algorithms can detect (analysis) the above mixed sequences and break down it ? i.e. detect and list out all sequences in it ? (Assume original sequence contain `<= 20` integers)

Thanks.

Regards,

LAM Chi-fung

Code based on Abhinav Mathur's algorithm, may need more debugging, all result is -1
;<

```
            #include <Array.au3>
    
    Func GetSequences(ByRef $arr)
        Local $arithmetic_seq[1], $geometric_seq[1]
        Local $n = UBound($arr)
    
        For $i = 0 To $n - 3
            For $j = $i + 1 To $n - 2
                Local $arithmetic = $arr[$i] & "|" & $arr[$j]
                Local $geometric = $arr[$i] & "|" & $arr[$j]
                Local $d = $arr[$j] - $arr[$i]
                Local $r = $arr[$j] / $arr[$i]
    
                $ArithTmp=$arr[$j]
                $GeoTmp=$arr[$j]
                For $k = $j + 1 To $n - 1
                    If ($arr[$k] - $ArithTmp) = $d Then
                        $arithmetic &= "|" & $arr[$k]
                        $ArithTmp=$arr[$k]
                    EndIf
    
                    If $arr[$k] / $GeoTmp = $r Then
                        $geometric &= "|" & $arr[$k]
                        $GeoTmp=$arr[$k]
                    EndIf
                Next
    
                If StringReplace($arithmetic, "|", "") <> $arr[$i] & $arr[$j] And StringLen($arithmetic) > 2 Then
                    _ArrayAdd($arithmetic_seq, StringSplit($arithmetic, "|", 2))
                EndIf
    
                If StringReplace($geometric, "|", "") <> $arr[$i] & $arr[$j] And StringLen($geometric) > 2 Then
                    _ArrayAdd($geometric_seq, StringSplit($geometric, "|", 2))
                EndIf
            Next
        Next
    
        ConsoleWrite("Sequences for " & _ArrayToString($arr) & @CRLF)
        ConsoleWrite("Arithmetic: " & @CRLF)
        _ArrayDisplay($arithmetic_seq)
    
        ; Clear the arithmetic sequence for the next iteration
        _ArrayDelete($arithmetic_seq, 1)
    
        ConsoleWrite("Geometric: " & @CRLF)
        _ArrayDisplay($geometric_seq)
    
        ; Clear the geometric sequence for the next iteration
        _ArrayDelete($geometric_seq, 1)
    EndFunc
    
    Local $sequence1[9] = [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14]
    Local $sequence2[9] = [2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 16, 27, 32, 81]
    Local $sequence3[9] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 16, 32]
    
    Local $sequences[3] = [$sequence1, $sequence2, $sequence3]
    
    For $i = 0 To UBound($sequences) - 1
        GetSequences($sequences[$i])
    Next
```

Comment: There are algorithms to find `Longest Arithmetic Subsequence` - perhaps you can find something useful in corresponding approaches

Comment: With 20 integers in the input, there are only 190 unique pairs. Each pair fully defines an arithmetic sequence, and may define a geometric sequence. It's a simple matter to see if the next value in the sequence exists in the input.

Comment: @Chi-fungLAM _list out all sequences_. Well, then `2 4 8 16 32` is not the only one. You need to consider `2 4 8`, `2 4 8 16` too in your output. And listing out all sequences will take exponential time anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original sequence has `N<=20`, it's easier to just brute force it. You could use a simple algorithm for this:

```
l, n = your_input_list, number_of_elements
arithmetic_seq, geometric_seq = [], []
for i in [1, n]:
    for j in [i+1, n]:
        arithmetic, geometric = [l[i], l[j]], [l[i], l[j]]
        d = l[j] - l[i]
        r = l[j] / l[i]
        while (arithmetic[-1] + d) in l:
            arithmetic.append(arithmetic[-1] + d)
        while (geometric[-1] * r) in l:
            geometric.append(geometric[-1] * r)
        if arithmetic.length > 2:
            arithmetic_seq.append(arithmetic)
        if geometric.length > 2:
            geometric_seq.append(geometric)
```

There are definitely some corner cases that you'll need to iron out (left as an exercise for the reader), but this approach should work for you. The `O(N^3)` order should pass for small sequences. For larger sequences, you could look at memoization by traversing the sequence from right to left, but that's out of scope for this answer.

##### Edit

Here's a quick implementation in Python:

```py
def get_sequences(l):
    arithmetic_seq, geometric_seq = [], []
    n = len(l)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            arithmetic, geometric = [l[i], l[j]], [l[i], l[j]]
            d = l[j] - l[i]
            r = l[j] / l[i]
            while (arithmetic[-1] + d) in l:
                arithmetic.append(arithmetic[-1] + d)
            while (geometric[-1] * r) in l:
                geometric.append(int(geometric[-1] * r))
            if len(arithmetic) > 2:
                arithmetic_seq.append(arithmetic)
            if len(geometric) > 2:
                geometric_seq.append(geometric)
                
    print("Sequences for ", l)
    print("Arithmetic: ", arithmetic_seq)
    print("Geometric: ", geometric_seq)


sequences = [[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14], [2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 16, 27, 32, 81], [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 16, 32]]
for seq in sequences:
    get_sequences(seq)
```

This outputs:

```
Sequences for  [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14]
Arithmetic:  [[2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 5, 7, 9], [3, 6, 9], [5, 6, 7], [5, 7, 9], [6, 10, 14]]
Geometric:  []
Sequences for  [2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 16, 27, 32, 81]
Arithmetic:  [[2, 3, 4], [2, 9, 16]]
Geometric:  [[2, 4, 8, 16, 32], [2, 8, 32], [3, 9, 27, 81], [4, 8, 16, 32], [8, 16, 32], [9, 27, 81]]
Sequences for  [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 16, 32]
Arithmetic:  [[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8], [2, 9, 16], [3, 4, 5]]
Geometric:  [[2, 4, 8, 16, 32], [2, 8, 32], [4, 8, 16, 32], [8, 16, 32]]
```

So the algorithm is fairly correct. You need to debug your implementation, since I'm not sure about the language you've used for it.

Comment: Implement with AutoIT (see edited post) but all result is -1... need more debugging ;<

Comment: @Chi-fungLAM edited the answer. You can see the algorithm functions as expected.

Comment: Eventually work out the code (see the edited post), thanks a lot.